# wp all import script to custom post image gallery

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, import

This post has been edited on 30 Nov 2015 and I have answered it myself. The correct script is at the bottom of this post. Thanks and good luck!

The problem:

To explain, I am working on localhost using MAMP, I am using WP ALL IMPORT plugin to get data into wordpress..I have a theme called BOOK YOUR TRAVEL. It has a custom posts and one particular custom field called "accommodation_images".  It stores image ids in whole array which is serialized. For long I did not realize that I did not have to serialize it my self.  I found scripts for similar purpose and have tried working with them.

I managed to get all images imported and attached with the plugin, and then importing to custom field "accommodation_images" was harder. as soon as it hits foreach I get empty array. when I comment foreach loop I get one entry  only if I use following line

```
$atts[] = array("image" =>$attid);
```

The single entry was obviously last one as it loops trough all..

but it is in a right format:

```
a:1:{i:0;a:1:{s:5:"image";s:5:"55079";}}
```

This is how the entry should look like in the db when more then 1

```
a:3:{i:0;a:1:{s:5:"image";s:5:"16487";}i:1;a:1:{s:5:"image";s:5:"77726";}i:2;a:1:{s:5:"image";s:5:"77722";}}
```

unserialize shows this array as

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [image] => 16487
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [image] => 77726
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [image] => 77722
    )

)
```

Below is the code that I have been working around

```
 //This hook is called after WP All Import creates/updates a post meta.
//$pid – the ID of the post/page/Custom Post Type that was just created.
//$attid – the ID of the attachment
//$image_filepath – the full path to the file: C:\path\to\wordpress\wp-content\uploads\2010\05\filename.png

add_action('pmxi_gallery_image', 'update_images_meta', 10, 3);
function update_images_meta( $pid, $attid, $image_filepath ) {
//$attachment = get_post($attid);
// do something with $attachment image

// Get all the image attachments for the post
$param = array(
        'post_parent'       => $pid, 
        'post_type'         => 'attachment', 
        'post_mime_type'    => 'image'
);

$attachments = get_posts($param);

// Initialize the array
$atts = array();

// Fill the array with attachment ID's
  foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    //$atts[] = $attachment->ID;
    array_push($atts, array("image" =>$attid));
    //$atts[] = array("image" =>$attid);

 }
    //$serialized = serialize($atts);
    //echo $serialized;

    // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
    //remove_action( 'save_post', 'update_images_meta', 10 );

    // Update the post's meta field with the attachment arrays
    update_post_meta($pid, 'accommodation_images', $atts);

    // renable save post action
    //add_action( 'save_post', 'update_images_meta', 10 );

}
?>
```

I needed to fix the loop in order to get the rest of the images added to array.

==================================================

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(UPDATE) after much time spent learning php I have found a solution.....

THE ANSWER: 30 Nov 2015 - I found a way to do this and I hope it helps someone. You have to make sure that images that you are testing with have produced attachments otherwise it will obviously not work. I have forced it and fixed that problem by setting plugin WP ALL IMPORT to rename images as it uploads them different then it was previously, so it created new attachments. good luck!

```
<?php
//This hook is called after WP All Import creates/updates a post      attachment file(s).
add_action('pmxi_gallery_image', 'update_images_meta', 10, 3);
function update_images_meta($pid, $attid, $image_filepath)
{

$attachments = get_children(array(
    'post_parent' => $pid,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image'
));

//print_r($result);
$atts = array();
// Fill the array with attachment ID's

foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
    array_push($atts, array(
        "image" => "$attachment->ID"
    ));
}

//echo '<pre>'.print_r($attachments,true).'</pre>'; //for testing
//echo '<pre>'.print_r($attachment,true).'</pre>'; //for testing

// unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
remove_action('save_post', 'update_images_meta', 10);

// Update the post's meta field with the attachment arrays
update_post_meta($pid, 'accommodation_images', $atts);

// renable save post action
add_action('save_post', 'update_images_meta', 10);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of Borisio's script.

```
<?php

//This hook is called after WP All Import creates/updates a post attachment file(s)
add_action('pmxi_gallery_image', 'add_images_ids_to_meta', 20, 3);
function add_images_ids_to_meta($post_id, $attid, $image_filepath)
{
    $attachments = get_children(array(
        'post_parent' => $post_id,
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image'
    ));

    $atts = array();
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment)
        $atts[] = $attachment->ID;

    // Update the post's meta field with the attachments ids
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'gallery_images_ids', serialize($atts));
}
?>
```

This one saves the images IDs in a meta field. I had to remove those "add_action" and "remove_action" because they were breaking the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the Macr1408 version a bit, so that it works with a custom "gallery" type field created with ACF Pro or JetEngine:

```php
<?php

//This hook is called after WP All Import creates/updates a post attachment file(s)
add_action('pmxi_gallery_image', 'add_images_ids_to_meta', 20, 3);
function add_images_ids_to_meta($post_id, $attid, $image_filepath)
{
    $attachments = $attid;
    if ( !empty($post->prop-galeria) ) $attachments .= $post->prop-galeria;
    
    // Aquí puedes reemplazar el nombre del campo meta por el que estes necesites
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'prop-galeria', $attachments);
    
}
?>
```

This is because the gallery field groups the IDs of each attachment separated by a comma.